# send a sms in java using sinch

Tags: java, sms, send, sinch

I'm trying  to send a sms in java.
I'm using the code given in yhis link:
https://developers.sinch.com/docs/send-sms-in-java
I have an account in sinch.
the compiler displays the following message:
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL:

```
https://us.sms.api.sinch.com/v1/sms/+15144651057
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sms.Sms.main(Sms.java:37)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to url encode the + sign to %2B

Hope it helps